# adding value count as label for each bar in bar chart in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, charts

I have a bar chart like this

here is my chart

[image]

I have created the chart by,

```
y_pos=np.arange(len(plot_label))

plt.bar(y_pos, plot_value, align='center', alpha=0.5 )
plt.xticks(y_pos, plot_label)
plt.ylabel('axis')
plt.title('Title')
```

I want to add the value counts at the top of each bar, for example as a label.

Comment: see the answer to the question I flagged as duplicate -- basically you only have to replace the label in that answer with the value count.

Comment: @Mel  how can I change the values for bar_vertical, they gave  for barh

Comment: @ThomasKühn not working I replaced the label

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html

Comment: It solved my problem what to do now

Comment: shall I delete this question as it is duplicate ?

Comment: As this question is now marked as duplicate, it is completely your choice. It may usually be beneficial not to delete duplicates as they might help others to find the answer more easily (different questions use different wordings for the same problem, different searches then lead to the same answers). However, here, I do not see much benefit as the question essentially uses the same wording. The takehome message from this is rather: Next time, please seach for an answer yourself instead of letting others do it for you.